# Derivation of bias of LASSO in the ortnormal case

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, bias

In the following lecture slides by Breheny, P. (2016) titled "Adaptive lasso, MCP, and SCAD" from the High Dimensional Data Analysis course at the University of Iowa, slide 2 presents the definition of the bias of the lasso in the orthonormal case. However, Breheny does not provide a derivation, proof, or source for this definition. Could anyone assist in clarifying /proofing that?

He states that the following can be shown for the orthonormal LASSO case:

E | $\hat{\beta_j}$- $\beta_j$ | = 0 if $\beta_j$ = 0

E | $\hat{\beta_j}$- $\beta_j$ | $\approx$ $\beta_j$ if | $\beta_j$ | in (0;$\lambda$)

E | $\hat{\beta_j}$- $\beta_j$ | $\approx$ $\lambda$ if | $\beta_j$ | > $\lambda$

Breheny, P. (2016). [Adaptive lasso, MCP, and SCAD](https://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/7240/s21/notes/3-03.pdf). Slides. High Dimensional Data Analysis, University of Iowa. Slide 2.